# Mongoosastic plugin doesn't update nested objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

So the project consists of the next stack, NodeJS, Express, Mongodb, ElasticSearch. For indexing to elastic search we use the plugin mongoosastic.

I have the following models which are having the 1:M relation between themselves and whenever I update the group, I want the group to be updated in the user object as well.
So if I update the group, it is just updated in the Group index in ElasticSearch and not also in the user index. But if I then update the user again, the group object is properly actualized.
It should be something with the es_type and es_include_in_parent but things are just not working either way.

```
const UserSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  group: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'groups',
    es_indexed: true,
    es_type: 'nested',
    es_include_in_parent: true
  }
  }, { timestamps: true } as SchemaOptions);

UserSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {..elasticSearchConfig,
  index: 'users',
  populate: [
    {path: 'group', model: 'groups'}
  ]}
);
export const UserModel = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema, 'users');
```

and

```
export const GroupSchema: mongoose.Schema = extendBaseSchema(new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
  web: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
  users: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users',
      es_indexed: true,
      es_type: 'nested',
      es_include_in_parent: true
    }
  ],
}));

GroupSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {...elasticSearchConfig,
  index: 'groups'
});
export const GroupModel = mongoose.model('groups', GroupSchema, 'groups');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter `es_schema` e.g. should solve your problem.

```
es_schema:User.schema
```